# Git API call on Github account on government Organization

Tags: curl, github-api, hostname, github-enterprise, egovernment

Trying to creae a remote repo regular github account with below command

```
$ curl -u 'USER':'TOKEN' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"REPO"}'
```

this works fine.

If my github account is in government org. say https://github.xyz.gov   then

```
$ curl -u 'USER':'TOKEN' https://api.github.xyz.gov/user/repos -d '{"name":"REPO"}'
```

gives below error,

```
Could not resolve host: api.github.xyz.gov
```

Trying to create at user level, I also need to create repo on Organization level apart from user level later. What is issue here.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git, and probably doesn't belong on StackOverflow at all but rather on SuperUser or similar.

Comment: Where is official github document link mention for curl -u 'USER':'TOKEN' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"REPO"}'

Comment: GitHub documentation will only say what you must supply in your HTML; curl documentation will tell you how curl *can* supply that, provided that it can. But your main issue here is that `api.github.xyz.gov` is not resolving as a host name, presumably because it is not actually a host name, or (if it *is* a host name) because of some name-resolver issue.